# Why is PHP's zip_read() returning false?

Tags: php, zip

Why is PHP's zip_read() returning false? I've used this same script before, and it returned true.

```
$zip = zip_open("/tmp/ayb/test.zip");
if(is_resource($zip))
{
    $zip_read=zip_read($zip);
    echo($zip_read?'true':'false');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts don't magically invert their behaviour for no reason. You changed something. You did something wrong. Don't blame the script. The ZIP got corrupted, or it's a different ZIP, or it's not there any more.

The [relevant manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-read.php) tells us:

> **Returns** a directory entry resource for later use with the `zip_entry_`... functions, or **FALSE if there are no more entries to read**, or an error code if an error occurred.

Note that this means you should be testing `$zip_read` for more than basic truthiness. You should be examining it more closely for its precise value, and take your debugging from there.

Comment: `zip_open()` shows it is there.  Any recommendations on where to troubleshoot?

Comment: @user1032531: Open it in WinZip. What do you see? What have you changed since you last ran the script? We do not have enough information to tell you why this script has magically inverted its behaviour. You have not provided reproduction steps.

Comment: +1.  I think you are correct in that it is a corrupted zip.  Sorry for the false alarm and "blaming" the script.  I will continue to research and post any findings.

Comment: Giving my last post, am I better off deleting this post, or keeping it open?

Comment: @user1032531: I think it's a deletion situation!

Comment: Ugg, I can't delete.  Guess I get to accept the thrashing I deserve.

Comment: For the record, was caused by the zip being empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to zipped zip archive with normal compession. And check is zip has a password or no. And then dump value:

```
var_dump($zip_read);
```

Answer (score 0):

The zip file is empty.

This is the correct answer.